# Technical Recommendations for Reporting Solution on SharePoint Server 2019 & SP Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, reporting

We have a SharePoint Server 2013 based product which we are maintaining for last 6+ years. Now, we are in the process of revamping this product to SharePoint Server 2019 and SharePoint Online using React-based SharePoint Framework along with Kendo UI (Telerik). For the same, we would need your technical guidance on the Reporting solution: -

Currently, for SP 2013 we are using SSRS as a reporting solution, however SSRS can’t be compatible with SP Online. As such, we are in process of finalizing the reporting solution that should be compatible in both SharePoint on premise (SharePoint server 2019) and SharePoint Online. Please note that for SharePoint on premise, clients may not go for any cloud offering for reporting (like Power BI) as this may expose their data to the cloud.

Please suggest the reporting solution suitable for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Power BI Report Server is on-prem, as is SSRS w/ the SharePoint webparts for on-prem.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server-sharepoint/report-viewer-web-part-sharepoint-site?view=sql-server-ver15

Ultimately, if I were a generic customer, I would want a solution to fit what I have. This likely means supporting both SSRS for on-prem scenarios and PBI for SPO.